# Apache-arrow JS implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a MEAN stack application that connects to customer databases and third-party data. From JS front end I need to be able to read parquet and big-data CSV files. In this regard please clarify my understanding :

1. I cannot read parquet file using arrow libraries directly (due to this issue [JIRA#2786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2786)). I have to use something like parquetjs-lite for this.
2. To read big-data CSV into apache-arrow, I have to first use Python (pyarrow) to convert CSV to arrow format (as in [here](https://observablehq.com/@theneuralbit/using-apache-arrow-js-with-large-datasets)) and then read the arrow file in my JS application.
   a). If (2)  above is correct then can I convert any third-party CSV to arrow or should I have a predefined schema ahead of time ?
   b). Are nulls and NaNs allowed in the CSV .

Thanks

Comment: Have you found anything re. point 2?

Comment: I went a different way so didn't get a chance to complete what I started out for, but I had followed Pauls'  (Paul Taylor - who contributes to Apache Arrow) sample here - https://github.com/trxcllnt/csv-to-arrow-js  . Hope it helps. regards